# 'Var' does not exist in current context (Lost in my my method)

Tags: c#, string, methods, console, var

Newb here doing some thing very dumb I'm sure.

I am attempting to carry a working line of code into a method. However when I do this, the code no longer returns the string variable 'selection' like i thought it would and does not return it when i try to test print it to confirm that I have it.

What I was expecting to happen is that GetSelection() would call GetString to ask the user to select B, L or D and depending on user input, it would return the selection which would then print to the console.

Code:

```
while (PlayAgain())
{
     GetSelection("(B)reakfast | (L)unch | (D)inner\n");
     Console.WriteLine("You Selected: " + selection); 
}
```

My methods:

```
public String GetString(String txtStr)
{
     Console.Write(txtStr + ": ");
     return Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
}

public String GetSelection(String txtStr)
{
     String selection = GetString("(B)reakfast | (L)unch | (D)inner\n");
     return selection;
}

public Boolean PlayAgain()
{
     String answer = GetString("Meal recommendation (Y) or (N)? ").ToLower().Trim();
     return answer == "y";
}
```

Please know that I have already tried to google this question and read some good stuff, but i'm not connecting/understanding what I'm reading deeply enough to understand my mistake. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
GetSelection("(B)reakfast | (L)unch | (D)inner\n");
```

you are calling  `GetSelection` but you didn't store returning value. Use this:

```
var selection =  GetSelection("(B)reakfast | (L)unch | (D)inner\n");
Console.WriteLine("You Selected: " + selection);
```

Comment: Thank you I will explore this and try to internalize it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is `selction` is local variable to the method `GetSelection`. So you cannot access `section` in code

to resolve this change is you code is like as below , means that you need to store value coming from the method `GetSelection` and display it.

```
while (PlayAgain())
{
    var selection= GetSelection("(B)reakfast | (L)unch | (D)inner\n");
     Console.WriteLine("You Selected: " + selection); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will explore this and try to internalize what you are saying. Thank. Will report back with results.

Comment: This worked. Thank you for a great answer - You've give a really solid answer and helped me to understand the context of my problem at a deeper level then i realized (code is fun - frustrating but FUN!) I guess i was think that String is Var, but that isn't necessarily true i guess? So much awesomeness to understand - thank you Pranay Rana!